# Jmeter doesn't upload files while replaying

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to replay a script in jmeter which has to upload a file in the transaction. The user is able to login when I replay but the file doesn't get uploaded.

How do I overcome this??

Comment: Don't forget to accept answer if it fixes your issue so that it's helpful to others

Answer (score 1):

Put the files to upload in jmeter/bin folder.

Read:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html

> Uploading files
>
> Some browsers (e.g. Firefox and Opera) don't include the full name of a file when uploading files. This can cause the JMeter proxy server to fail. One solution is to ensure that any files to be uploaded are in the JMeter working directory, either by copying the files there or by starting JMeter in the directory containing the files.